# Pass an object and a member function as parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a template function which calls a member function of a class.

```
template<typename T>
void call(T owner, void (T::*func)())
{
    (owner.func());
}
```

and the usage:

```
Foo a;
call(a, &Foo::printname);
```

But the compiler returns error C2664.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func` is a pointer-to-member-function; there's a special syntax for calling them:

```
(owner.*func)();
```